# «В свою очередь». Обособление или необособление?

Tags: запятые

Я сконфужен тем, когда *в свою очередь* — вводное. Где нужны запятые?

> Ананас имеет много калорий, яблоко(,) в свою очередь(,) — мало.

> Она сказал, что ей неинтересно(,) а я(,) в свою очередь(,) ответил, что мне не неинтересно.

> Надо запятые с *между прочим* использовать. С *между тем*(,) в свою очередь(,) они не нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Ананас имеет много калорий, яблоко, в свою очередь, — мало***;

***Она сказал, что ей неинтересно, а я в свою очередь ответил, что мне не неинтересно***;

***Надо запятые с «между прочим» использовать. С «между тем», в свою очередь, они не нужны***.

По [«Розенталю», пункт 9-7](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122), запятые в вариантах 1 и 3 **нужны**, так как оборот **в свою очередь** употреблëн в **переносном значении**.

Во втором, в свою очередь, запятые **не нужны**, т. к. употреблëн в значении *со своей стороны*, *в ответ*.

Вот, чтобы долго не искать:

> Сочетание в свою очередь, если оно употреблено в значении, близком к прямому, или в значении ‘в ответ; со своей стороны’ , вводным не является и запятыми не выделяется: «Надо, детки, мягче относиться друг к другу», — говорила мать, целуя в свою очередь дочь (Г.‑М.) — ‘когда наступила ее очередь’; Он в свою очередь спросил у меня.
>
> Употребленное в переносном значении сочетание в свою очередь приобретает значение вводности и выделяется запятыми: Среди газетных жанров различаются жанры информационные, аналитические и художественно-публицистические; среди последних, в свою очередь, выделяются очерк, фельетон, памфлет; Усадив меня за работу, Владислав, в свою очередь, не тратил времени впустую (Бахм.).

Comment: «_**каллорий, аблоко**_» ❓❓❓Исправьте, Максим!

Comment: С _каллориями_ всë нормально.

Comment: Максим, можно поинтересоваться, откуда "ка**лл**ории"? Вы прям заставили усомниться. *От лат. calor - тепло, жар*. Вроде бы правильно с одной Л и в русском.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец А, извините, не знал.

Answer (score 1):

В первом предложении **только тире** (без запятой):

*Ананас имеет много калорий, **а яблоко, в свою очередь —** мало.*

**Пояснение**

1. Тире ставится при обособлении вводного слова в  **неполной** конструкции.

Пример постановки **тире** после слова *"главное"* **[у Розенталя, пункт 9(11)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)**

2. Желательно использовать **сопоставительный союз *А*.**

Comment: Это как дополнение, но запятые тоже можно использовать.

Comment: Какой смысл в этой запятой?  Тире обозначает неполную конструкцию, а сочетание знаков воспринимается как единый знак, совершенно там неуместный.  Надо выбирать не возможный вариант, а наиболее подходящий (без "можно").  Ну и по поводу союза А тоже скажите что-нибудь.

Comment: Без союза обойтись можно, но с союзом, безусловно, лучше. Ладно, может, и правда этот более верный.

Comment: Я так не думаю. Бессмыслица какая-то. У Розенталя в 11-м подпункту совсем другой случай.

Comment: Полное предложение: Ананас имеет много калорий, а яблоко, в свою очередь,  имеет калорий мало.  СТИЛИСТИКА? Ну не знаю, можно ли ИМЕТЬ в свою очередь даже в переносном смысле. Ну да ладно, рассмотрим само предложение.  В неполном варианте сокращается значительный объем текста и заменяется тире. Может ли запятая пойти под СОКРАЩЕНИЕ? Думаю, что да.  Зачем в конце предложения лепить "единый знак"?  Теорию надо найти более походящую, но на практике обособление тире, безусловно, встречается. И по интонации там выразительная ПАУЗА делается.  А у Розенталя тоже неясный пример, что-то там напутали.